# Unable display comma value in cell content using data validation with explicit list constraint using poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI (v 3.8) for adding drop down list for cell with data 
validation.But comma(,) value is separated to another value in list.Other than comma (,) its working fine and check below screen shot

[image: Generated excel file through Apache poi]

Code

```
DataValidation dataValidation = null;
DataValidationConstraint constraint = null;
DataValidationHelper validationHelper = null;
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet1=(XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("sheet1");

validationHelper=new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet1);
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new  CellRangeAddressList(1,10,1,1);
constraint =validationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"SELECT","A,B", "C%D","B$D", "C&D","A( A & B)"});
dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint, addressList);
dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);      
sheet1.addValidationData(dataValidation);
FileOutputStream fileOut;
        try {
            fileOut = new FileOutputStream("f:\\test-1.xlsx");
              wb.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I tried to replace with ASCII code.But appended ascii code value instead of comma(,).Please help on this

Comment: `Apache poi` cannot do what `Excel` itself cannot do. So how would you set that explicit list constraint in `Excel`'s [Data Validation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) dialog?

Comment: I passed String[] to validationHelper class

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
validationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(value)
```

choose

```
validationHelper.createFormulaListConstraint(value);
```

You will have to create a separate list of names, but it will work.

```
Name namedCell = book.createName();
namedCell.setNameName("list");
namedCell.setRefersToFormula("'" + sheet.getSheetName() + "'!$" + "A$1:$" + "A$2");

Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("item");
```

and in "**value**" you specify the name of the list of names